# Why variable assignation doesnt work as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have a collection of persons, and a collection of adresses. In each person, there's an id for the adress. We try do do a 'join-like' in JavaScript, and it's not possible to add new field in the return object.

```
var ret;
app.get('/tp/show/method', function (req, res) {
    ret={};
    User2Model.find(function(err, users) {
        if(err){
            console.error('Error find: '+err);
        }
        var last_id;
        for(var user_id in users){
            last_id=users[user_id]._id;
            ret[last_id]=users[user_id];
        }
        for(var user_id in users){
            AdrModel.find({ 'user_id': users[user_id]['id_adr'] },function(err, adr) {
                if (err){
                    console.error('Error find: '+err);
                }
                for(var i in adr){
                    for(var user_id in users){
                        if (users[user_id].id_adr==adr[i].user_id) {

                            /* ok id found, so add all adresses to the result: */
                            /* The following line doesn't work: */
                            ret[users[user_id]._id]=adr;

                            if(users[user_id]._id==last_id){
                                var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
                                var query = url_parts.query;
                                res.setHeader(
                                    'content-type', 'application/javascript'
                                );
                                json=query.callback+'('+JSON.stringify({
                                    data:{success: 1, value: ret }
                                })+')';
                                res.send(json);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The variable `ret` is global, so we should be able to modify it, but the return result just accept when we override some of the properties already there. It doesn't work if we try to add new properties like "addr". What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure..but I think "    var ret=[];.....ret={};" is something wrong.

Comment: Your code looks really strange. As `break;` will only leave the loop is is inside, you will still have the `for(var i in adr)` loop (It might not be a problem at all). Assuming you use `express` (which is not mentioned by you) it looks like that you will/want to call `res.send` for every `AdrModel.find` but that is not possible with `res.send`. On every request you reset `ret` by doing `ret={}` so why do you want that it is global. Anyway the problem and what you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: @t.niese You're right, there's one 'break' missing, and you're right again: this doesn't change the behavior even though the code is not correct. What I may miss is the way nodejs and mangoose behave. I want to do a "join" on two different collections: person and address. When I do a "find()" it's launched in background - or something like that and the loop continues, so I dont know when the loop will finish, and the only way I found to remember the person when the "address" callback is called is to put it in a global variable. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is all wrong. *(Hint: In the face of a JavaScript block that nests 9 levels of curly braces it's generally a pretty safe bet to say that it's all wrong.)* You are in need of a promise library that handles all those asynchronous calls for you. The attempt you make here can never work.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you very much for your comment, but you didn't give me a clue where to look to do it well...

Comment: Why you're doing the same for two times in a row?
for(var user_id in users){
...
}
for(var user_id in users){{
...
}

Other thing, note you're declaring the user_id twice in the same function scope.

Comment: Put a breakpoint into the ret[users[user_id]._id]=adr line and verify if users[user_id]._id is undefined.

Comment: @RubensPinheiro `user_id` is not defined twice in the same scope. The first belongs to `function(err, users) {` the second belongs to the callback `function(err, adr) {` the second loop is done after the first loop completely finished as the callback is async.

Comment: try ret[users[user_id]._id+'']=adr;

Comment: @OlivierPons I was getting to that. ;) See below.

Comment: @OlivierPons, they are defined twice in the 'for's -> var user_id.
If you verify with jslint, it will hint you to "Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function."

Like:
var user_id;
for(user_id in users){
}
for(user_id in users){
}

Comment: @OlivierPons I have an additional question about your API: Does it allow fetching a list of address object in one step or are you forced to fetch every address individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I indicated in comments to @Tomalak's solution above, events can also be used to manage program flow in an async environment.

Here's an alternate *partial* solution that uses just that approach.

> Please note that of the various ways of accomplishing this goal (I know of at least three, or four if you accept that the pain of "Callback Hell" can be ameliorated through the use of callbacks defined outside of and only referenced inline by their caller), I prefer using events since they are a more natural way for me to think about this class of problem.

#### Take-aways

1. Events are an efficient and easily understandable way to manage program flow in an async programming environment.
2. Rather than simple triggers, events can be used transport any data so they can be used further on for any purpose.
3. Events can easily call other events without worrying about scope.
4. Event processing allows you to *unwind* your code such that it becomes easier to track, and thus debug, as well as reducing the burden on the stack typically seen in deeply nested or recursive code. In other words, events are fast and very memory efficient.

#### Explanation

The code first defines two mocks:

1. an App class which provides a `get` method, allowing us to mock out the OP's `app` instance, and
2. a User2Model singleton that provides a `find` function for the same purpose.

It then documents the following events:

1. `error` - which is called on any errors to print a message to console and exit the program
2. `get` - which is fired with the result of the `app.get` method and immediately fires the `processUsers` event with {req:req,res:res}
3. `processUsers` - fired by the `get` event handler with a mocked array of user objects, sets up a results object and a last_id value, and then calls the `nextUser` event.
4. `nextUser` - fired by the `processUsers` event which picks the next user off the users array, sets evt.last_id, adds the user to the evt.results, and emits itself, or if there are no users left on the evt.users array, emits `complete`
5. `complete` - fired by nextUser and simply prints a message to console.

Event handlers are next defined using the 'on'+eventName convention.

And finally, we

1. define an eventHandlers object, to map handlers to their appropriate events,
2. instantiate our `app` instance, and
3. invoke its `get` method with a callback that simply emits a `get` event to start the ball rolling.

I've documented most of the solution using jsdoc and added logging messages to show progress as each event is emitted and its handler invoked. The result of the run is included after the code. (The http req and res objects have been commented out of the log messages for the sake of brevity.)

One final note, while this example is 269 lines long, most of it is documentation.

The actual code (without the mocks) is only about 20 or 25 lines.

#### Code

```
/*

 Example of using events to orchestrate program flow in an async
 environment.

 */

var util = require('util'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

// mocks

/**
 * Class for app object (MOCK)
 * @constructor
 * @augments EventEmitter
 */
var App = function (handlers) {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.init(handlers);
};
util.inherits(App, EventEmitter);

/**
 * Inits instance by setting event handlers
 *
 * @param {object} handlers
 * @returns {App}
 */
App.prototype.init = function (handlers) {
  var self = this;
  // set event handlers
  Object.keys(handlers).forEach(function (name) {
    self.on(name, handlers[name]);
  });
  return self;
};

/**
 * Invokes callback with req and res
 * @param uri
 * @param {App~getCallback} cb
 */
App.prototype.get = function (uri, cb) {

  console.log('in app.get');

  var req = {uri: uri},
      res = {uri: uri};
  /**
   * @callback App~getCallback
   * @param {object} req - http request
   * @param {object} res - http response
   * @fires {App#event:get}
   */
  cb(req, res);
};

/**
 * Data access adapter - (MOCK)
 * @type {object}
 */
var User2Model = {};
/**
 *
 * @param {User2Model~findCallback} cb
 */
User2Model.find = function (cb) {
  var err = null,
      users = [
        {_id: 1},
        {_id: 2}
      ];
  /**
   * @callback User2Model~findCallback
   * @param {Error} err
   * @param {Array} users
   */
  cb(err, users);
};


// events

/**
 * Error event.
 *
 * @event App#error
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} [req] - http request
 * @property {object} [res] - http response
 * @property {string} where - name of the function in which the error occurred
 * @property {Error} err - the error object
 */

/**
 * Get event - called with the result of app.get
 *
 * @event App#get
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} req - http request
 * @property {object} res - http response
 */

/**
 * ProcessUsers event - called
 *
 * @event App#processUsers
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} req - http request
 * @property {object} res - http response
 * @property {Array} users - users
 */

/**
 * NextUser event.
 *
 * @event App#nextUser
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} req - http request
 * @property {object} res - http response
 * @property {Array} users
 * @property {*} last_id
 * @property {object} result
 */

/**
 * Complete event.
 *
 * @event App#complete
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} req - http request
 * @property {object} res - http response
 * @property {Array} users
 * @property {*} last_id
 * @property {object} result
 */

// event handlers

/**
 * Generic error handler
 *
 * @param {App#event:error} evt
 *
 * @listens App#error
 */
var onError = function (evt) {
  console.error('program error in %s: %s', evt.where, evt.err);
  process.exit(-1);
};

/**
 * Event handler called with result of app.get
 *
 * @param {App#event:get} evt - the event object
 *
 * @listens App#appGet
 * @fires App#error
 * @fires App#processUsers
 */
var onGet = function (evt) {
  console.log('in onGet');
  var self = this;
  User2Model.find(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('\tonGet emits an error');
      return self.emit('error', {
        res:evt.res,
        req:evt.req,
        where: 'User2Model.find',
        err: err
      });
    }
    self.emit('processUsers', {
      //req:req,
      //res:res,
      users: users
    });
  });
};

/**
 * Handler called to process users array returned from User2Model.find
 *
 * @param {App#event:processUsers} evt - event object
 * @property {object} req - http request
 * @property {object} res - http response
 * @property {Array} users - array of Users
 *
 * @listens {App#event:processUsers}
 * @fires {App#event:nextUser}
 */
var onProcessUsers = function (evt) {
  console.log('in onProcessUsers: %s', util.inspect(evt));
  var self = this;
  evt.last_id = null;
  evt.result = {};
  self.emit('nextUser', evt);
};

/**
 * Handler called to process a single user
 *
 * @param evt
 * @property {Array} users
 * @property {*} last_id
 * @property {object} result
 *
 * @listens {App#event:nextUser}
 * @emits {App#event:nextUser}
 * @emits {App#event:complete}
 */
var onNextUser = function (evt) {
  var self = this;

  console.log('in onNextUser: %s', util.inspect(evt));

  if (!(Array.isArray(evt.users) && evt.users.length > 0)) {
    return self.emit('complete', evt);
  }

  var user = evt.users.shift();

  evt.last_id = user._id;

  evt.result[evt.last_id] = user;

  self.emit('nextUser', evt);
};

/**
 * Handler invoked when processing is complete.
 *
 * @param evt
 * @property {Array} users
 * @property {*} last_id
 * @property {object} result
 */
var onComplete = function (evt) {
  console.log('in onComplete: %s', util.inspect(evt));
};

// main entry point

var eventHandlers = { // map our handlers to events
  error: onError,
  get: onGet,
  processUsers: onProcessUsers,
  nextUser: onNextUser,
  complete: onComplete
};

var app = new App(eventHandlers); // create our test runner.

app.get('/tp/show/method', function (req, res) { // and invoke it.
  app.emit('get', {
    req: req,
    res: res
  });
  /* note:
       For this example, req and res are added to the evt
       but are ignored.

       In a working application, they would be used to
       return a result or an error, should the need arise,
       via res.send().
   */
});
```

#### Result

```
in app.get
in onGet
in onProcessUsers: { users: [ { _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 } ] }
in onNextUser: { users: [ { _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 } ], last_id: null, result: {} }
in onNextUser: { users: [ { _id: 2 } ],
    last_id: 1,
    result: { '1': { _id: 1 } } }
in onNextUser: { users: [],
    last_id: 2,
    result: { '1': { _id: 1 }, '2': { _id: 2 } } }
in onComplete: { users: [],
    last_id: 2,
    result: { '1': { _id: 1 }, '2': { _id: 2 } } }
```

Comment: Excellently explained and documented answer. You did a way better job at that than I did in mine. What I wonder about: Has `last_id` any higher purpose here? The OP tried to use it as a means to somehow know when to send the response, but in your code keeping it around doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Aside: I still think that not making promises the primary async interaction paradigm in node.js was easily the worst design decision they have made. Look at all the boilerplate you need to get that event-based system running... I'm sure it's partly a matter of acclimatization, but I find this kind of approach much less discoverable - everything is disjoint and I can't easily see what results and side-effects emitting an event will have.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your explanation, clear as water. Your code, which is very clean, takes 20-25 lines. With a very classical php architecture, it would be one line for a "SELECT... JOIN " then 3 lines to do the loop and echo json_encode() the result. So it just made it clear to me: NodeJS is only for very specifics needs, because maintainability is far worse than classical Php/Python approaches.

Comment: @OlivierPons Sorry, that's a nonsense statement. You can do the `SELECT ... JOIN` + a three line loop in JS as well, what keeps you from doing it?

Comment: @Tomalak Maintainability. The main problem in all software - all the time, even from the beginning of computing, is the cost of maintenance - sorry for my English, but I guess you know what I mean. Working in team means: make things as simple as possible if someone has to understand what you've done he'll do it very fast. The code you have to deal with NodeJS/JavaScript/asynchronous principles (all mixed) makes it hard for people to understand what you've done fast. It's not a problem of what you do it's a problem of the tools: NodeJS/JavaScript/asynchronous principles.

Comment: @Tomalak Maybe it's easy for you, but you seem to be very clever & smart. This just implies that 99% of your team mates wont understand easily what has been done, even though you're not responsible for this, it's those 3 things: NodeJS/JavaScript/asynchronous principles. Microsoft has given up with asynchronous and copy/pasted the synchronous TCP principles of Unix-based system because of this: as the client's need grow up, your code grow up and becomes just un-readable. Thus un-maintenable.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not criticizing you, but the "big idea": I would use this on very rare cases, when I need very fast reponse times. Only in this case. In all other cases, I'd go for LAMP solution.

Comment: @OlivierPons You are mixing things up. Code maintainability is a function of your own knowledge (which you can improve), but primarily of designing your application properly. "LAMP" or "Node" has nothing to do with it. Node is also not about fast response times. Node is a JavaScript runtime, nothing more, nothing less. And asynchronous behavior is a fact of life in *any* but the most trivial JavaScript program, no matter what the underlying system is. Get over it and learn how to use it to your advantage. Saying "but PHP is easier" will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm not sure what you mean by "boilerplate" since (other than the mocks I created to simulate the OP's original problem) there is nothing to the code other than requiring `EventEmitter` and writing some event handlers. If it is inconvenient or inappropriate to mixin EventEmitter into an existing object, you can always `var eventer=new EventEmitter()` to create an eventable object. So, by my count, with the `require` and the `new`, there are only two lines of "boilerplate". ;)

Comment: @Tomalak, last_id is only there to mirror (a portion of) the OP's example. In truth, it serves no purpose in my solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, regarding the visibility of using events this way, I'd suggest you look at `EventEmitter2` which provides the same API as `EventEmitter`, but adds the ability of using wildcards as event targets. So a simple `eventer.on("*",function(evt){console.dir(evt);})` will dump every event to the console to assist debugging.

Comment: @RobRaisch Hi again Rob, I've tried your solution but the big problem I'm facing is that I have to build the answer *before the end* of the function `http.createServer(function (request, response) {}`, because I need to fill up `response` variable with `writeHead()` then `end()` and your sample let this function end and handles the database search *after*. How to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical problem caused by trying to handle asynchronous code with synchronous means. Your entire attempt is unfixable, you need to scrap it.

One widely adopted way of handling asynchronous code without going insane is by using promises.

Here is what your code could look like if you used a promise library. For the sake of the example I'm using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) here.

```
var findAddress = Promise.promisify(AdrModel.find);
var findUsers = Promise.promisify(User2Model.find);

// a helper function that accepts a user object and resolves the address ID
function attachAddrToUser(user) {
    return findAddress({
        user_id: user.id_adr
    }).then(function (address) {
        user.address = address;
        return user;
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error("error finding address for user ID " + user.id_user, e);
    });
}

findUsers().then(function (users) {
    var pending = [], id_user;
    for (id_user in users) {
        pending.push(attachAddrToUser(users[id_user]));
    }
    Promise.all(pending).then(function (users) {
        // all done, build and send response JSON here
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // don't forget to add error handling
    });
});
```

working jsFiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/2hdru6ma/

Note: `attachAddrToUser()` modifies the user object that you pass to it. This is not *entirely* clean, but it's effective in this context.

Comment: OMG! This is surely the right way to do this, but I'm just wondering how it is possible to make big applications with such -no offense, it's surely the best possible code- hard to read code. How about maintenability?

Comment: *Hard to read?* I'm not sure about that when I compare it to your code. ;) If the concept of promises is foreign to you then it might be a bit difficult at first. Once you learn how promises work this is instantly obvious.

Comment: That being said, I'm sure it can be improved even more but I had to make assumptions about your API and data model, so it's not easy.

Comment: The same can be accomplished using events only, which I find a cleaner and more natural means of managing async program flow.

Comment: @Rob I didn't say this is the *only* way. And you are more than welcome to post an event-based approach. I'd be very interested in having an alternative solution to look at.

Comment: @Tomalak, I did not say or even imply that you believed your approach to be the only way to accomplish the OP's goal, only that of the many possible strategies that can be used to orchestrate program flow in an async environment, I prefer events. When I have a moment, I'll post my preferred solution. Thanks for expressing an interest.

Comment: @Tomalak, see my answer below.

Comment: And just my 2c, but I've always thought the nomenclature of "Promises" was poorly chosen and only hinders understanding for the uninitiated. They do not "promise" anything, nor are they "Futures" (which I find an even worse term). Promises are simply a means of orchestrating both synchronous and asynchronous functions using the same modality. For synchronous functions, they do exactly what you expect, run the function and pass a result to the next step. For asynchronous functions, they provide their own callbacks that functionally do the same thing. And sadly no, I know of no better name.

Comment: Every higher concept in programming hinders understanding for the uninitiated. Events appear to be the easier concept only because they have been around longer. However, joining synchronous and asynchronous functions under the same paradigm allows strikingly elegant, expressive, *functional* code. You can look at six lines of unfamiliar code and instantly see what will happen (`this().then()`). In an event based approach you see one line (`emit()`) and then you need to pull out pen and paper to create a map of who talks to whom.

Comment: @Rob FWIW, here's an eye-opening article that I highly recommend: [The If Works: Callbacks are imperative, promises are functional: Node’s biggest missed opportunity](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I get it. If the function AdrModel.find is **async**, you're setting this values always to the last user.

This occurs because a async function will be executed after the for block end. So, the value of the user_id in all AdrModel.find calls will be always the same, because the saved scope where the async call is executed. Let's say your users are this collection

```
[{_id: 0}, {_id:2}, {_id: 3}]
```

So the calls of AdrModel.find will always use user_id -> 3 value:

```
ret[users[user_id]._id]=adr; //this guy will use user_id == 3, three times
```

**EDIT**
To resolve your problem is simple, **modularize** your code.
Create a function to do this resource gathering:

```
function setAdr(userId){
    AdrModel.find({ 'user_id': userId },function(err, adr) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then, you call it in your 'for':

```
...
for(var user_id in users){
    setAdr(users[user_id].id_adr);
    ...
```

This way you'll save a safe scope for each async call.

Comment: That explains the *why* part, but the *what to do about it* part is missing.

Comment: As your described, you can use 'promises' (to me this is the better way too!) or in this case, as @OlivierPons say that it's hard to read, he can try the above solution too. :)

Comment: That would work, but the hard bit, i.e. knowing when all addresses are resolved (so they can be sent to the client), is not addressed by this solution.